# SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I have an ejb file that contains some files and a message driven bean.

When I run my ejb file, I got this error.

EJB Container initialization error.

However, when I remove the message driven bean from my ejb. My ejb can run smoothly.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Error of Glassfish server here
http://pastebin.com/HkyRFnwE

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
java.lang.Exception
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:233)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.<init>(MessageBeanContainer.java:205)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:121)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:230)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:108)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:186)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.getActivationSpec(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:257)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inbound.ConnectorMessageBeanClient.setup(ConnectorMessageBeanClient.java:213)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.util.SetMethodAction.handleException(SetMethodAction.java:152)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.util.SetMethodAction.run(SetMethodAction.java:136)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.util.SetMethodAction.run(SetMethodAction.java:105)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MQJMSRA_AS4001: setSubscriptionDurability:Invalid subscriptionDurability=durable
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.ActivationSpec.setSubscriptionDurability(ActivationSpec.java:537)
        ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your EJB module uses the EJBContainer. A word of caution is that the EJBContainer only supports EJB lite which does not include remote EJBs nor MDBs. Refer to [this link for details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24972/embedejb.htm)

EJBContainer is mainly for testing in JUnit, it is not meant for production code.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MQJMSRA_AS4001:
>   setSubscriptionDurability:Invalid subscriptionDurability=durable

because the [subscriptionDurability](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-1065/ghrxj/index.html) property value is case sensitive and you specified it as lowercase, i.e. "durable" instead of the correct value of **Durable** (i.e. with first letter capitalized)

I've had the same problem and this was the cause.

> This property enables you to configure the durability of the topic
>   subscriber. Durable subscribers can survive any disconnection from the
>   JMS server.
>
> The valid values are Durable and NonDurable.

The problem can be reproduced with the following MDB (Message Driven Bean):

```
@JMSDestinationDefinition(name = "BookingTopic", interfaceName = "javax.jms.Topic", 
        resourceAdapter = "jmsra", destinationName = "BookingTopic") @MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "BookingTopic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "durable"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "BookingTopic"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "BookingTopic") }) public class ReservationNotifier implements MessageListener {
    private static final Logger loggger = Logger.getLogger(ReservationNotifier.class.getSimpleName());

    public ReservationNotifier() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            Booking booking = (Booking) ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
            loggger.log(Level.INFO, "Sending e-mail containing reservation information to {0}", booking.getCustomer().getEmail());
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            loggger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error reading booking from topic");
        }
    }

}
```